# findpeaks - MINPEAKDISTANCE

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to understand how `MINPEAKDISTANCE` works. I returned to the documentation, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html), but it wasn't very clear how this parameter works.

Can you kindly clarify it a bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Minimum peak separation Specify the minimum peak distance, or minimum
>   separation between peaks as a positive integer. You can use the
>   'MINPEAKDISTANCE' option to specify that the algorithm ignore small
>   peaks that occur in the neighborhood of a larger peak. When you
>   specify a value for 'MINPEAKDISTANCE', the algorithm initially
>   identifies all the peaks in the input data and sorts those peaks in
>   descending order. Beginning with the largest peak, the algorithm
>   ignores all identified peaks not separated by more than the value of
>   'MINPEAKDISTANCE'. Default: 1

So if you consider your peak heights as values in the "y" direction, then the separation that this is talking about is in the "x" direction. So for example look at this image (from [Matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/peak-analysis.html) and if you have the image processing toolbox you can get the data too `load noisyecg.mat`):

[image]

lets say you just want to identify thos 4 big distinct peaks, but not the hundreds of little peaks caused by noise, setting `MINPEAKDISTANCE` is a feasible way accomplish this because the noisy peaks are at a much higher frequency, i.e. they are closer to each other in the "x" direction, or have a smaller distance separating them than the big peaks do. So choosing a large enough `MINPEAKDISTANCE`, say `100` or `350` for example depending on what peaks you're interested in, would help you to not detect these undesired noise peaks.

Try `findpeaks` on this data with different `MINPEAKDISTANCE` values and see what you get!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got noisy data, you may find that instead of one solid peak, you get lots of small ones (see the folowing image).

[image: A digital signal with uniform noise applied]

The important data here is when the signal is high and when it is low - you don't care about small variations in value, you only want to use one of those peaks and not look at all the smaller local ones around it. If you know the frequency of your signal (i.e. how often the peaks should occur), you can tell the function to ensure that the peaks are separated by a certain amount.

In the above example, the peak is every 15 milliseconds and lasts for 5 milliseconds, so you might set your MINPEAKDISTANCE parameter to 15 or so.